# How to iterate a string and add string to every position?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need something like this in TSQL

```
string myString = "123";
for (int i = 0;  i < myString.Length; i++)
{
   myString.Insert("ABC", i);
}
Output "ABC1ABC2ABC3"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
declare input as varchar(1000) -- Choose the appropriate size
declare output as varchar(1000) -- Choose the appropriate size

select @input = '123', @output = ''

declare @i int

select @i = 0

while @i < len(@input)
begin
    select @i = @i + 1

    select @output = @output + 'ABC' + substring(@input, @i, 1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the length of the original string as your loop limit and the substring() function to append the nth char and 'ABC' to a buffer string.